# Need help creating a simple Regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex that validates a string (letters, numbers, spaces or special characters) but can't have  words bigger than 35 characters, for example:

Valid: this a test string

Invalid: this is a testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt string

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure do you need a regex ? Why don't you check the string length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9~@#\^\$&\*\(\)-_\+=\[\]\{\}\|\\,\.\?\s]{,35}
```

you can add other `special characters`  as you desired.